Selenium automate AEM Editor
I'm trying to automate the editor of AEM, just I have an issue about the selectors inside of this iframe, so I would like if anyone knows how to works with type of iframe, due to the content is dynamic but the classes are always the same,but the class is not found by the selenium
iframe = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe')))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
lunch = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'Dniwja_spectrum-Button Dniwja_spectrum-BaseButton Dniwja_i18nFontFamily Dniwja_spectrum-FocusRing Dniwja_spectrum-FocusRing-ring')))

I tried as well run a Javascript inside that find the element and click it, but it's not working yet :(
driver.execute_script("""
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName("Dniwja_spectrum-Button Dniwja_spectrum-BaseButton Dniwja_i18nFontFamily Dniwja_spectrum-FocusRing Dniwja_spectrum-FocusRing-ring");
    console.log(elements);
    //not defined elements[0], but the list of elements is printed on console
""")


I want to click "Launch" button


Any advice is welcome
